# Inserting new column in existing xls file keeping the format intact In Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl, jxls

I want to insert a new column in between the existing columns of the excel which is in .xls format using Java retaining the existing format. Is there any api to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Apache POI library to modify an Excel file.

Quick Guide: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

You'll want to:

- Load your Excel file as a `Workbook`.
- Open the correct `Sheet`.
- Insert your new column using [Sheet#shiftColumns](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#shiftColumns-int-int-int-).
- Save the modified `Workbook` back to an Excel file.